# JBrowserDriver for crawing data get call takes 15 secs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I am trying to crawl data using JBrowserDriver.
The below line takes about 15 secs

```
val driver = JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).userAgent(UserAgent.CHROME).build())
```

Is there any way to make it faster?